# Extending MapView

Tags: android

I need to make some changes to two methods in MapView so I've done a class that extends it. When I'm trying to use this class the app crashes and with the Log: Unable to start activity.

`GameMapActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.maps.MapView cannot be cast to com.lemonbyte.games.lbg.mapViewC`

Because of `mapViewC mapView = (mapViewC) findViewById(R.id.mapview);`
My class is below
    public class mapViewC extends MapView{

```
public mapViewC(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context,attrs);
}

 public mapViewC(Context context, String apiKey)
    {
        super(context, apiKey);

    }

public mapViewC(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    //limit zoom level 
    if(getZoomLevel() >15){
        getController().setZoom(15);
        getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(0, 0));
        //dont draw as it will just be blank and then jump
        return;
    }

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? :) thank you!

Comment: show your layout.xml file also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `MapView` element in your layout xml as `com.lemonbyte.games.lbg.mapViewC` (also, as a standard, classes are named with an upper-case first letter).